# c# round to two decimal places

Tags: c#, linq

How can I round to two decimal places in these scenario. This is not working

```
      List<decimal> abc = new List<decimal> { 500, 500 };
      List<decimal> abcd = new List<decimal> { 12, 100 };
      var cd = string.Join(",",  abc.Zip(abcd, (q1, q2) => ((Math.Round(q2,2) / Math.Round(q1, 2)) * 100));
```

Comment: So, most of the question code (zip) and tags (asp, linq) are not relevant and there is no clarification of “not working”. Should probably have this process and expectations down better by now..

Comment: Think about what your code does. You round integer-valued decimal quantities to two decimal points. So you take a number like 500, round it to two decimal points and get 500.00, which is *exactly equal* to 500. After all this co-OP rounding you do some division and multiplication. Remember 12m/500m is exactly equal to 12.00m/500.00m (the "m" suffixes indicate decimal literals). As @cihanyakar's answer indicates, what you really want to do is do the division first, then do the rounding. Doing the rounding first achieve nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add excepted result and the purpose on your question.
Check this:

```cs
    List<decimal> abc = new List<decimal> { 500, 500 };
    List<decimal> abcd = new List<decimal> { 12, 100 };
    var cd = string.Join(",", abc.Zip(abcd, (q1, q2) => Math.Round(q2 / q1 * 100.00M, 2)));
```